# Missing Google Play Protect Translation files

Tags: android, translation

Where do I find the strings.xml translation files for Google Play Protect?

I have the latest com.android.vending, gms and Android-9.0-Pie-XMLs-master.

What i find is     "Play Protect regularly checks your apps and device for harmful behaviour. You'll be notified of any security risks found."
in vending res/values-en-rGB/strings.xml as well as in rIN, rAU etc.

What I need is the translated strings such as:

> German: Play Protect prüft meine Apps und dein Gerat regelmäßig auf shadliches Verhalten
>   Italian: Play Protect controlla regolarmente le tue app e il tuo dispositivo per verificare che non ci siano comportamenti dannosi.
>   Polish: Play Protect regularnie sprawdza aplikacje i urządzenia pod kątem szkodliwego dzialania.
>   France (FR): Play Protect vérifie régulièrement que le comportement de vos applicatons et de votre appareil n'est pas nuisible.
>   France (CA): Play Protect vérifie régulièrement qu'aucun comportement nuisible ne perturbe le fonctionnement de vos applications et de votre appareil

...

All these were re-written from a real Android 9 Phone. But there are some Chinese/Thai that i CANNOT write...

Therefore I'd need to find the translated strings.xml for this to be solved. Its not in res folder of vending neither in Android-9.0-Pie-XMLs-master.

Or maybe i can export them from Android System itself? Have emulators on Android Studio but dont know where to look for them.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

The missing translations are in assets/metaresources.arsc file.

I only found JEB Decompiler to be able to decompile it, but is extracting it in ANSI format (cant use Unicode) and its not able to be read. Anyone has this file decoded to share?